# Fiware response 503 - Service unavailable

Tags: fiware-orion

we are getting this error, since 11.30 GMT+2, when trying to request information from this URL http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/queryContext?limit='+str(limit)+'&details=on

503 - Service Unavailable
Error in IDM communication

Later this morning it worked fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the service get back up during the morning, it doesn't seem to be a major problem. This kind of glitches happen from time to time.