# Error when running first MapReduce job

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I've testing a Cosmos instance base on this QSG (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md), everything works appropriately until I reach **Step 5: Run your first MapReduce job**.

I get "Error in IDM communication" message by running below code:

```
curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/netzahdzc/jobs" -d '{"jar":"jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","class_name":"wordcount","args":["hdfs://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org/user/netzahdzc/testdir","hdfs://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org/user/netzahdzc/testoutput"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxx"
```

The reason I'm writing is because I wonder if as it is implied on this post ([Fiware response 503 - Service unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986050/fiware-response-503-service-unavailable)) this still a glitch or I am doing something wrong.

This is the last test I did:

```
curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/USERNAME/jars" -d '{"jar":"jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","class_name":"wordcount","args":["hdfs://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/SERVICE/SERVICE_PATH/OBJECT_ID/OBJECT_ID.txt","hdfs://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/testoutput"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: XXXXXXXXXX"
```

This is the reply:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any hint?

Comment: This was a problem with the server itself, some emporal files where not properly deleted and the server run out of disk. Now it should be working.

Comment: it's working, thanks.

Comment: hi @frb I'm testing the MapReduce example after awhile, and seems that the problem came back. It is returning same error as before (i.e., Empty reply from server). Could you please proceed with same mechanism as before to remove those temporal files?